# Docking tabs in Chrome (windows), Is it gone

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

There was a feature in Chrome (at least on windows) documented [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/166203?hl=en).
For example:

> If you use Windows and you want to quickly resize your browser window, drag the window or tab to pre-defined docking positions on your computer monitor or browser. When the docking icon appears, release the mouse over the icon to have the tab snap in place.

This functionality doesn't seem to work anymore.
Any way to turn it on again?

Comment: You can try and use a previous version but if the feature was removed then no you can't restore it

Comment: @Ramhound as you can see, it is still a documented feature.

Comment: This is functionality that is different to Windows Snap, yea?

Comment: Windows Snap seems to work on a whole window, even of the window is the Chrome browser. It doesn't work on a single Chrome tab

Comment: Just because their is a page on the feature doesn't mean it's still a feature that still exists google isn't great about getting rid of pages like that

Comment: @Ramhound is pretty much correct. There is an option at the bottom of the page to 'rate' how useful it is. I reported it as incorrect, I suggest you do as well.

Comment: For reference, what Chrome version are you on? Did it ever work for you when using a previous release?